# Fabric v2 override --hosts behaviour

Tags: python, fabric

Using fabric (version 2.4) I am trying to override the behaviour of the `--hosts` CLI flag. 
Namely, instead of passing the full host URL, I would like to pass an alias and then have the full connection details looked up in e.g. a configuration file.

E.g

`fab --hosts=alias1 myTask`

I'm struggling finding the best place to implement this behaviour - at one point is the `Connection` set up? It is seemingly before control is handed over to my `task` function. Does this require that I override `Connection`....if so, is there a way to configure fabric to use my custom class?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to pass an alias to fabric instead of passing the full url/address of the host.

That is possible and you don't need to override anything. What you need is creating an `config` file in your local `.ssh` folder on your OS. In that config file just write down your alias like this:

```
Host AliasHost
     Hostname YOUR_SERVER_URL
     User YOUR_REMOTE_USER
     Port 22
```

Then you can call your fabric script normally with `--host AliasHost`.

Please check this blog post for more information 
https://peshmerge.io/how-to-use-fabric-to-deploy-a-flask-web-application/